# Why is my controller calling different API when there is no match API for the request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa, postman

I am working on a Spring boot project, it produces strange behaviors, for ex:

I have two APIs as follow

**Controller file**

```
@GetMapping("/list/employees")
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getEmployees(){
    List<Employee> list = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(list, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK );
}

@GetMapping("employee/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") long id) throws RuntimeException{
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employee,new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Service file**

```
/*  return all employees */
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
    List<Employee> listEmployee = employeeRepo.findAll();
    if(listEmployee.size()>0){
        return listEmployee;
    }else{
        return new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }
}

/*
    RETURN SINGLE EMPLOYEE BY ID
 */

public Employee getEmployee(long id) throws RuntimeException{
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepo.findById(id);
    if(employee.isPresent()){
        return employee.get();
    }else{
         new RuntimeException("Record not found");
        }
    return null;
}
```

But running them in **Postman** gives weird output, for ex:

**Correct behavior of second API returning single employee**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/employee/3
{
"id": 3,
"firstName": "Caption",
"lastName": "America",
"email": "cap@marvel.com"
```

}

**Incorrect behavior of the same API (I am typing the wrong path this time)**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/employees/3
```

**The API path is wrong (employees/3)**

```
{
"firstName": "Caption",
"lastName": "America",
"email": "cap@marvel.com",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/employees/3"
    },
    "employee": {
        "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/employees/3"
    }
}
```

}

same behavior with the root URI, I have not triggered any action with home URI but still gives output like in the above API.

what can be the reason for these unwanted API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have Spring Data Rest on your class path.  It will automatically wire paths based on the repositories.  That second response is a HATEOAS response.

A simple test would be to check maven/gradle.  If you see spring-data-rest,  comment it out and try again.

Comment: There was Spring Data Rest in my classpath. after commenting on that dependency, it worked fine.

Comment: Happy to help, Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unwanted API calls. That is the way HATEOS response is represented as stated in the documentation:

> The fundamental idea of hypermedia is to enrich the representation of a resource with hypermedia elements. The simplest form of that are links. They indicate a client that it can navigate to a certain resource. The semantics of a related resource are defined in a so-called link relation.

As suggested above, try to look for spring boot hateos dependency and comment or remove that, then it should revert back to normal REST JSON response.

If you are using maven, look for :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

if you are using gradle, look for :

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
```